# Reader Transformer Monad

Tags: haskell

```
newtype ReaderT r m a :: * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *
```

I cannot understand how to understand above expression, especially 
`* -> (* -> *) -> * -> *`

Comment: Your question and example is not so clear

Comment: it's the kind-signature - a `*` stands for a type - so it tells you that `r` is a type, `m` is a type-constructor (like `Maybe` or `IO` - you give those a type and they return one) and `a` is a type - the result (which is `ReaderT r m a`) is a type again - it's just there to help you understand the parts involved ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should actually be

```
ReaderT :: * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *
```

Loosely speaking, the type above is a the type of a function which takes an argument of type `*`, another of type `* -> *`, another of type `*`, and produces a result of type `*`.
The type `*` is the "type of all types". E.g. `Int :: *`, `Char :: *`, etc.

To avoid confusion, `*` is not really called "a type" but "a kind", to reflect that it works at an higher level. For instance, `'a'` has type `Char`, and `Char` has kind `*`.

Finally, the kind `* -> *` is the kind of unary type constructors, such as `Maybe`, `[]`, `IO`, `(,) Char`, `Either Bool`, etc. All of these take a type argument and return a type. The kind `* -> *` is also the kind of any functor, applicative, or monad.

So, if we have  type `r`, a type constructor `m` (typically, a monad), and a type `a`, we have:

```
r :: *
m :: (* -> *)
a :: *
ReaderT :: * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *
ReaderT r :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
ReaderT r m :: * -> *
ReaderT r m a :: *
```

Hence, when all three arguments are passed, the result `ReaderT r m a` is a type.

Comment: why `(* -> *)` is monad?

Comment: @Gilgamesz `* -> *` is not a monad, but if you have any monad `m`, then `m` must have kind `* -> *`. E.g. `m = Maybe`, or `m = IO`

Comment: `(,)` is `* -> * -> *` no? I thought you could not think of `* -> *` as `*`.

Comment: @jd823592 Yes, but `(,) Char` is `* -> *` (above there's an unfortunate automatically inserted line break...)

Comment: @chi oh sorry I did not notice that.